# Fix Inode checksum does not match inode while checking journal

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ext4

I have the following problem while trying to access and resize a partition on my **external hdd** which contains **Kubuntu 18.04 Lts**. This problem occured after I accidentally turned my computer off directly by pressing power button. I got the following output when trying to resize it from 465.24 GiB to 74.62 GiB.

```
Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda2 
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
/sbin/e2fsck: Inode checksum does not match inode while checking journal for /dev/sda2
e2fsck: Cannot proceed with file system check

/dev/sda2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sda2’: Error

Checking partition ‘/dev/sda2’ before resize/move failed. 
Move partition ‘/dev/sda2’ to the right by 8.00 KiB and shrink it from 465.24 GiB to 74.62 GiB: Error
```

Comment: Two things... 1.) Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results. 2.) You can't downsize without making sure that your total used disk space will fit into 74G. Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? Do you really want/need to resize?

Comment: I'm trying to access my disk.